# What does segmentation fault (core dumped ) mean?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, coredump

I'm trying to write a C program for mad libs game:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char color[20];
  char Noun[20];
  char celebrity[20];
  printf("Enter the color");
  scanf("%s", color);
  printf("enter the Noun");
  scanf("%s", Noun);
  printf("enter the celebrity");
  scanf("%s", celebrity);
  printf('roses are %s\n', color);
  printf('%s are blue\n', Noun);
  printf('I love %s\n', celebrity);
  return 0;
}
```

After I type in my input at the "shell> " prompt, gcc gives me the following error:

`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Why do I get this error?

Comment: `printf('` => `printf("`

Comment: read the warnings given by the compiler.

Comment: Your compiler clearly must have told about passing incorrect parameter type for `printf`. Don't just ignore the hints you are given.

Answer (score 4):

1. You don't limit the size of the scanned data (so it can write out of bounds if the input is larger than the len 20 arrays)
2. None of your arrays are initialized, so
3. Since you don't verify the return value from `scanf`, if a `scanf` fails, you'll try to read from uninitialized arrays
4. The last three of your format strings for your `printf` calls are using `'` as the delimiter, not `"`, so they're actually character literals (yes, it's weird that C allows this syntactically), and their numeric value is being interpreted as a pointer that likely points to pure garbage; replace the single quotes with double quotes (`"`).

#4 would almost certainly cause a segfault if the code got that far, but #1 could conceivably cause a segfault before you got to that point (and #2 and #3 could combine to cause a segfault if #4 was fixed).